# The multi-part identifier "MyNewDatabase.dbo.df_umts_relation.technology" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query as the below one:

```
UPDATE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
SET [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_rnc_rel] = 
(CASE WHEN UMT.target_vendor_rel = 'HUA' THEN carrier.rnc ELSE SHO.ucell_rnc END )
FROM [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation] UMT LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier] carrier
ON  UMT.n_cell_name = carrier.cell_name_umts
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[esn_umts_intra_sho] SHO
ON UMT.n_cell_name = SHO.ucell
WHERE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[technology] = 'UMTS'
```

as I found this error:

```
The multi-part identifier "MyNewDatabase.dbo.df_umts_relation.technology" could not be bound.
```

the query works fine without the `where` condition as the below:

```
UPDATE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
SET [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_rnc_rel] = 
(CASE WHEN UMT.target_vendor_rel = 'HUA' THEN carrier.rnc ELSE SHO.ucell_rnc END )
FROM [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation] UMT LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier] carrier
ON  UMT.n_cell_name = carrier.cell_name_umts
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[esn_umts_intra_sho] SHO
ON UMT.n_cell_name = SHO.ucell
```

So all I need to execute this query correctly using `WHERE`.

Comment: I suspect that SQL Server cannot find the "technology" field in the table, could you please add the schema for [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation] to your question?

Comment: you aliased the table `[MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]` as `UMT`, so the `WHERE` clause also needs to refer to `UMT`

Comment: Do NOT develop this habit. Your database connection will always have a current database and the sql code you write should refer to objects within the current database. Using 3-part names will make your code difficult to move to different environments. Only use 3-part names when you understand the consequences and you have a very good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my undestanding is correct you are using 2 alias for the table[MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
Try this.

```
UPDATE UMT
SET UMT.[target_rnc_rel] = (
        CASE 
            WHEN UMT.target_vendor_rel = 'HUA'
                THEN carrier.rnc
            ELSE SHO.ucell_rnc
            END
        )
FROM [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation] UMT
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier] carrier ON UMT.n_cell_name = carrier.cell_name_umts
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[esn_umts_intra_sho] SHO ON UMT.n_cell_name = SHO.ucell
WHERE UMT.[technology] = 'UMTS'
```